# python kivy android app crashes after api request

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

i just built an android app using python kivy/buildozer. The app crashes after i input my latitude and longitude and click the 'get conditions' button. here is the python/kivy code...
the app works as intended on my laptop.
just fyi... if your going to test this use latitude 37 and longitude 122.5 as i know the weather.gov api works for these.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


import requests
class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):

        self.title = 'SurfsApp!'

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')

        label1 = Label(text = 'SURFS APP!',size_hint = (1,.3), color = (0,0,1,1))
        btn1 = Button(text = 'Todays Conditions', size_hint = (1,.3))


        label2 = Label(text = 'Enter your latitude below',size_hint=(1,.1))


        label3 = Label(text = 'Enter your longitude below',size_hint=(1,.1))

        self.lon1 = str(122.5)
        self.lat1 = str(37)

        layout.add_widget(label1)
        layout.add_widget(label2)

        layout.add_widget(label3)

        layout.add_widget(btn1)

        def getconditions(*args,**kwargs):


            i = 0
            north = self.lat1
            west = self.lon1
            gps= str(north) +','+ '-' + str(west)
            url = 'https://api.weather.gov/points/'+ str(gps)
            headers = {'Token': 'tArcrKZYxRTCWPvhTcdBqyydHZnxLCJB'}
            response = requests.get(url)
            data = response.json()


#           print(data['properties']['forecastGridData'])

            url = data['properties']['forecastGridData']
            response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
            data = response.json()



            forecast = {'windSpeed': "{0:.1f}".format(data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][i]['value'] * 1.94384),
            'windDirection': data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][i]['value'],
            'primarySwellDirection':    data['properties']['primarySwellDirection']['values'][i]['value'],
            'primarySwellHeight':   int(data['properties']['primarySwellHeight']['values'][i]['value'] * 3.28084),
            'wavePeriod':               data['properties']['wavePeriod']['values'][i]['value'],
            'secondarySwellDirection':  data['properties']['secondarySwellDirection']['values'][i]['value'],
            'secondarySwellHeight': int(data['properties']['secondarySwellHeight']['values'][i]['value'] * 3.28084),
            'wavePeriod2':              data['properties']['wavePeriod2']['values'][i]['value'],
            }



            label1.text = ('windDirection: '       + str(forecast['windDirection']) + ' degrees' + 
            '\nwindspeed: '               + str(forecast['windSpeed']) + ' knots ' + 
            '\nprimarySwellDirection: '   + str(forecast['primarySwellDirection']) + ' degrees' +
            '\nprimarySwellHeight: '      + str(forecast['primarySwellHeight']) + ' feet' + 
            '\nwavePeriod: '              + str(forecast['wavePeriod']) + ' seconds' +
            '\nsecondarySwellDirection: ' + str(forecast['secondarySwellDirection']) + ' degrees' +
            '\nsecondarySwellHeight: '    + str(forecast['secondarySwellHeight']) + ' feet' +
            '\nwavePeriod2: '             + str(forecast['wavePeriod2']) + ' seconds'
            )





        btn1.bind(state = getconditions)


        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

and here is the buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = surfs app

# (str) Package name
package.name = srfsp13

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy,requests

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = all

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

wondering if it has something to do with android permissions or the requests module...or hopefully something i haven't thought of...

just spent a week getting buildozer to work in an ubuntu virtual environment on windows...
thanks in advance.

Comment: use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to get the logcat

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: i have internet permissions enabled in the .spec

Comment: ok, i edited it so it has preset lat and lon. just click the button. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the internet, you need to include the Android permissions for that in your `buildozer.spec`:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

Have a look at the [default spec file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kivy/buildozer/master/buildozer/default.spec)

Comment: i have internet permissions enabled in the .spec

Comment: I don't see it in the `.spec` file you posted.

Comment: sry. i didn't paste it properly. the full spec is shown above now. thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? If so, what is it?